# jQuery slider UI not sliding

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery slider UI for a slider in an audio player only the sliding function doesn't work when I set variables to it.

```
$('.body_container .slider').slider({

  value: 0,
  step: 0.01,
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  max: song.duration,
  animate: true,  

  slide: function(event,ui) {             
    manualSeek = true;
  },
  stop:function(event,ui) {
    manualSeek = false;         
    song.currentTime = ui.value;
  }
});
```

In firebug it comes up with the error `closestHandle is undefined`. `closestHandle` comesout of the jQuery UI file.

However it does work when I set no options in the function and just leave the events but obviously I need to set the options;

```
$('.body_container .slider').slider({

  slide: function(event,ui) {             
    manualSeek = true;
  },
  stop:function(event,ui) {
    manualSeek = false;         
    song.currentTime = ui.value;
  }
});
```

Comment: Try adding the options back in one at time and seeing at which point it breaks. `value` defaults to `0` so that isn't needed anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A little late, but make sure that song.duration is a number. You can use parseFloat() to be sure.

Comment: thanks alot I too faced similar issue. resolved by your answer. thanks

Comment: Agreed. Usually happens when while initializing the slider one of the properties like step, min,max etc is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think song.duration is not defined.

Try removing the  following line:

```
max: song.duration,
```

or replacing it with this:

```
max: 100,
```

If it is song.duration that is not working, try using `console.log(song.duration);` with firebug to debug what is in that variable.