# jquery slider is not working as expected

Tags: jquery-ui, slider

I have the following slider

```
$( "#slider-min-bw" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: $("#BwLowerHidden").val(),
            max: $("#BwUpperHidden").val(), 
            values: [ $("#BwLowerHidden").val(), $("#BwUpperHidden").val() ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#slider-min-bw-range" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ] + "-" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
            });
        $( "#slider-min-bw-range" ).val(  $( "#slider-min-bw" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + "-" + $( "#slider-min-bw" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

When I alert like,

```
    alert($("#BwLowerHidden").val());
    alert($("#BwUpperHidden").val());
```

I get the values as 2 and 10000 . But on the UI, I only get one handler and range appears to be 2-2 instead of 2-10000. 
But at the same time, another slider like below, works perfectly as intended.

```
$( "#slider-min-dist" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: $("#DistLowerHidden").val(),
        max: $("#DistUpperHidden").val(),
        values: [ $("#DistLowerHidden").val(), $("#DistUpperHidden").val() ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#slider-min-dist-range" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ] + "-" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
        });
        $( "#slider-min-dist-range" ).val(  $( "#slider-min-dist" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +"-" + $( "#slider-min-dist" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

What could possibly be wrong in the first snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in this post,

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213054/jquery-slider-ui-not-sliding
```

the value should be a number.

Using a `parseInt()` did the trick.